# Error when trying to change view controllers with a button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have set up two separate view controllers in my main storyboard, each having a button. When the one button is pressed it changes to the second view controller and vice versa however, when i run the project and click the button i get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

...in the output box. this is my code for the button action in my first view controller:

```
@IBAction func addInfo(sender: AnyObject) {
    let view2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as ViewController2
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(view2, animated: true) //error: (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) on this line
}
```

I'm still new to Xcode and I'm busy working in beta4. ( I watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQXWsDNno8o&list=UUyKe4Xa8ki_YZiXtjuptFUA) and still no luck )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation to `UIViewController`:

> If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation
>   controller, this property contains the owning navigation controller.
>   This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a
>   navigation controller.

In your case, it look like `self.navigationController` returns `nil`. Check if your view controller is inside navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks! been looking everywhere for a solution... works perfect now :)

Answer (score 3):

Makesure that you have set the Identifier as view2. 
paste the console error log

Comment: Just checked the storyboard ID and it's definitely "view2". This is all i get in the console: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)"